# Salesforce Knowledge (Managed Package)

Tags: lightning, managed-package, knowledge

I tried to install the package in dev org and I got the error to enable Lightning knowledge.

**Your request to install package "CovrEdge Summer 2017" was unsuccessful. None of the data or setup information in your salesforce.com organization was affected.
If your install continues to fail, contact Salesforce CRM Support through your normal channels and provide the following information.
Organization: Ideas2it (00D28000001F9qq)
User: Siva kumar (00528000002HUEB)
Package: CovrEdge (04t1a000000EiOE)
Error Number: 491590030-526350 (1854556947)
Problem:
1. (Knowledge__kav.Master) Lightning Knowledge is not enabled, or you are in the unsupported Migration Stage
Knowledge__kav.Master: Lightning Knowledge is not enabled, or you are in the unsupported Migration Stage**

Then I enabled Lightning knowledge in dev org, now I am getting the below error,

**Your request to install package "CovrEdge Summer 2017" was unsuccessful. None of the data or setup information in your salesforce.com organization was affected.
If your install continues to fail, contact Salesforce CRM Support through your normal channels and provide the following information.
Organization: Ideas2it (00D28000001F9qq)
User: Siva kumar (00528000002HUEB)
Package: CovrEdge (04t1a000000EiOE)
Error Number: 491590030-533191 (1972235205)
Problem:
1. (Knowledge__kav) When Lightning Knowledge is enabled, you can’t add an article type.
Knowledge__kav: When Lightning Knowledge is enabled, you can’t add an article type.
2. (Knowledge__kav-Knowledge Layout) Parent entity failed to deploy
Knowledge__kav-Knowledge Layout: Parent entity failed to deploy**

Once we enable Lightning knowledge in org we can't revert it. Any ways to remove the knowledge from manged package or any other work around?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, as mentioned in the error message, Contact Salesforce CRM Support through your normal channels and provide the information you provided above to them.

Next time, maybe you can try sharing the managed package name (i'm assuming it is on the appexchange) alongside the installation instructions (or reference towards them?)